# Plotting a dictionary containing a dictionary using matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, matplotlib

I'm attempting to create a stacked bar graph with matplotlib with the x axis being female and male in this case and the y axis showing the number of "Yes" for each gender. Then I'd stack the graph with another bar graph showing the number of "No" for each gender.

Current dictionary:

```
{'Female': {'Yes': 34, 'No': 4},
 'Male': {'Yes': 59, 'No': 4},
 'Other': {'Yes': 5, 'No': 0}}
```

I'm not sure how to manipulate the dictionary to fit the parameters matplotlib requires for the bar method.

Getting the dictionary's key and values returns

```
dict_keys(['Female', 'Male', 'Other'])
dict_values([{'Yes': 34, 'No': 4}, {'Yes': 59, 'No': 4}, {'Yes': 5, 'No': 0}])
```

I'm not sure how to split the Yes and No in the dictionary to separate arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is essentially a table, it seems easiest to me to  use [Pandas plotting](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Female': {'Yes': 34, 'No': 4},
     'Male': {'Yes': 59, 'No': 4},
     'Other': {'Yes': 5, 'No': 0}})

df[['Female', 'Male']].T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

(`.T` stands for for [`.transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html))

[image: the plot]